# How to retrieve roles list to AssignTo dropdown in issue creation form?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

In forge api documentation we can find: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-industry_roles-GET/

It gives us all available roles in projcet. On https://docs.b360.autodesk.com it seems to be reduced to roles which available users have (and fore example shows only 3 roles insted of all 36) 
How can we connect users with roles?

Comment: Can you show me which page of BIM360 Docs you refer to? I am not sure about connecting users with roles, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @ZhongWu By: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-GET/ we can get users list. I can't find there an information about their roles. But on https://docs.b360.autodesk.com  in assignTo dropdown I can see only a subgroup of all roles available in project. There are only roles which are assigned to available users in this project. I don't know how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, The API to GET the users information of a project is not exposed yet, I know it's a frequently asked request, and our engineering team is still working on this. Without this API, I can not think a way to identify all the industry roles that are available within this project. Sorry for the limitation.

Comment: Can we get users which can be assingTo issue in selected project? I've realized now that forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-GET gives us users witch access for any project. How can I determine if particular user has access to particular project?

Comment: that's unfortunately the current limitation, you can assign a user to a project by https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-POST/, but can not get the user that is assigned to a project as i mentioned before.